# Understanding products in category theory: When is $H(\prod b_i) = \prod H(b_i) \text{ or } H(\prod b_i) \cong \prod H(b_i)$?

Tags: category-theory, definition, examples-counterexamples

Let $J$ be a small discrete category, $B$ be a category with all products, and $F: J \rightarrow B$ by $i \mapsto b_i$.  Let $\prod b_i$ be the limit of $F$ with limiting cone $v : \prod b_i \dot \rightarrow F$.  If $H: B \rightarrow C$ is another functor, what must be true of $H$ so that

$$Hv : H(\prod b_i) \dot \rightarrow HF$$ is a limiting cone where $$H(\prod b_i) = \prod H(b_i) \text{ or } H(\prod b_i) \cong \prod H(b_i)$$
?

Comment: The functor $F$ appears to be completely irrelevant to your question...

Comment: I have edited the question to better reflect what I am trying to understand.

Comment: So you're asking, if some product object happens to also be the limit of some other diagram, and the product is preserved by a functor, when will the other limit also be preserved?

Comment: I'm asking what must be true of a functor $H$ so that $Hv$ is a limiting cone and either one of the two relationships "equality" or "isomorphic" is true between the images of the product or product of the images.

Comment: But what does the functor $F$ have to do with anything?  Is $J$ supposed to be discrete and $F$ is the functor that sends $i\in J$ to $b_i$?

Comment: Yes, $J$ is a small discrete category and $F: J \rightarrow B$ by $i \mapsto b_i$.  I'll add this to the question.

Comment: Comparing stuff up to equality is [evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what conditions a functor sends products to products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974537/under-what-conditions-a-functor-sends-products-to-products)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the statement $H(\prod b_i) = \prod H(b_i)$ just doesn't make sense.  Products are only defined up to isomorphism, so it is only meaningful to ask whether they are isomorphic to things, not whether they are equal to things.  In some contexts you might fix one particular product to call "the product", so that it is meaningful to ask whether equality holds, but it will basically never hold.  If you ever see anyone writing $=$ in this context, that is probably just lazy notation for "isomorphic" (or maybe "naturally isomorphic").

The statement $H(\prod b_i) \cong \prod H(b_i)$ makes sense, but still isn't a very natural thing to talk about.  You pretty much never care about whether $H(\prod b_i)$ is isomorphic to $\prod H(b_i)$ by any map at all.  Rather, you care about whether it is isomorphic in a way that is "compatible" with the projections from the products.

What this compatibility means is exactly that $Hv$ is a limiting cone.  If $Hv$ is a limiting cone, then that means $H(\prod b_i)$ is a product of the objects $Hb_i$, and so it is isomorphic to any chosen product of them and we can say $H(\prod b_i) \cong \prod H(b_i)$.

So, then, when will $Hv$ be a limiting cone?  There isn't any particularly good answer to that.  It's a limiting cone when it's a limiting cone.  Your question is kind of like asking: if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, when is $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$?  It's true when it's true, and if it happens to be true that is a useful fact, but there isn't any simpler way to describe *when* it's true.  It's just a question you can ask and answer of each individual case you encounter.

One important sufficient condition for it to be true is if $H$ has a left adjoint.  In fact, a functor which is a right adjoint (i.e., which has a left adjoint) always preserves *all* limits (in this sense of sending limiting cones to limiting cones), not just products.

Comment: So $H(\prod b_i) \cong \prod H(b_i)$ whether or not $Hv$ is a preserved limiting cone?

Comment: Nice answer, +1. It might be worthy to add that when the context allows it, exactness corresponds to preserving finite (co)limits.

Comment: No.  If $Hv$ is a limiting cone, then they are isomorphic.  They might happen to be isomorphic even if $Hv$ is not a limiting cone, but that's not very useful usually so we don't care about that.  In most cases, though, they are _not_ isomorphic (and $Hv$ is not a limiting cone).

Comment: In fact, in most cases $\prod H(b_i)$ doesn't even exist, since you did not assume that $C$ has products.

Comment: So if $C$ has all products and $Hv$ is a limiting cone then we're guaranteed that $\cong$, and if $Hv$ is not a limiting cone then it depends on $C$ and $H$?

Comment: That's correct.  Actually, in the first case, you don't need to assume $C$ has all products, or any products.  If you know that $Hv$ is a limiting cone, that means that this particular product does exist.